# Unable to locate controller name of SD card

Tags: usb-flash-drive, data-recovery, hardware-failure, sd-card

I am trying to recover my SD card as instructed [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/692929/can-t-access-usb-flash-drive-anymore/693176#693176) as it became write protected, however, I tried both tools ChipGenius and ChipEasy but both are not reporting what is the controller name.

The card is suppost to be Samsung Class 10 16 GB Micro SD card:

[image]

Any advice how to find the controller name, so I can try to reflash it?

[image: ChipGenius]
[image: CghipEasy]

Comment: Throw it away. Don't waste your time.

Comment: Sadly @Tetsujin is right. If the device is 100% genuine Samsung but doesn’t clearly show that when you check it, it means the card is dead.

Comment: Interestingly, I can read the card if I put the SD adapter in locked position, so not completely dead. If unlock it, then it cannot be read. I wanted to see whether something can be done for learning purposes, not so much that I care about the card. @Giacomo1968 how certain are you that the fact the controller name is not displayed, means the card is dead, considering I can read from it?

Comment: chipgenius only works with USB sticks.

Comment: "Interestingly, I can read the card if I put the SD adapter in locked position, so not completely dead. If unlock it, then it cannot be read" - So? Recover the data and then bin it.