# How to repair a micro SD card with I/O errors?

Tags: sd-card, io, micro-sd-card, write-protect

I have an 32 GB micro SD card which was able to let me copy data, but not alter data. After a lot of research, I came to the conclusion that the ['card detects a potential fault within itself. The drive will go into write-protected mode to prevent data loss.'](http://forums.sandisk.com/t5/Mobile-memory-professional-cards/Error-with-SanDisk-micro-SDXC-64GB-card/td-p/333569). Now this guy says that you will not be able to repair that, but after some more research I came across this thread: [How to format/repair a write-protected USB drive with I/O errors?](https://superuser.com/questions/689439/how-to-format-repair-a-write-protected-usb-drive-with-i-o-errors) Which stated that you have only to reprogram the micro controller. Now the thing is: You can only use micro SD cards (on a PC) with an adapter, and the problem with that is the VID and PID are the same (because it's reading the adapter and not the SD card), no matter which card you put into the adapter. So my question is similar to the one that is linked here, but a bit more complex.

So: **How can I repair this card?**

EDIT: I don't know the vendor of this card. And it doesn't matter how complex this will be, just tell me a method.

Comment: You can’t repair physical failures of the memory cells. Replace it, why would you even take a chance of storing data on this drive?

Comment: @Appleoddity How do you mean physical? The SD has no physical damage

Comment: It has but not something you can see. All drives fail and SD cards more often than other types of memory.

Comment: The process of erasing flash memory cells is slightly destructive and will eventually lead to a memory cell that can no longer store data. The card is as good as dead. Replace it.

Comment: @HugoWoesthuis Memory cells just like a hard drive are physical objects. They have wear and tear. They go bad.

Comment: If you're going to discard it anyway, try formatting after salvaging your data. It might bypass bad cells... or not.